# How to fix could not intialize class "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook" used poi-5.2.0 version

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have used (poi,poi-ooxml,poi-ooxml-lite) as 5.2.0, xmlbeans-5.0.3, commons-io-2.11.0
as jars but still getting could not intialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook. During runtime is poi-ooxml-5.2.0 expecting any other jar as dependency. Not used maven,  dependencies just added in Build path and in lib.
Is there anything missing. could someone help on it.
poi-ooxml 5.2.1 or poi-ooxml-5.2.2, are there any runtime dependecies?

Comment: The class `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` is contained in `poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar`. So that jar must be in class path while compile time and while run time. And the class loader must be able to read that jar.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml can be used to visualise the dependencies - you will need more jars (eg curvesapi, commons-compress, etc) - I would suggest you invest some time studying how to use a build tool - here is a POI example with Gradle - https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-gradle-example

Comment: Could you please provide us the code you are trying to execute?